Can't deploy a solution on another environment because of dependencies with other tables that use systemuser table
I'm working in Power Platform. I have two different solutions that use some different custom tables but both of them with lookup columns against the table systemuser.
Now I want to deploy one of that solutions on a production environment. My problem is that when dataverse check for dependencies, it asks me to include the custom tables from the other solution because a dependency with the systemuser table.
I don't want to include tables from the other solution in my deployment. What can I do?
This is a dummy scenary of what is happening. I'm developing these two very different solutions in the same environment (I will not open a new environment for each solution I have to develop).

Now I finished the Solution A and trying to deploy it on production environment. The pipeline asks me to include the table Orders in my solution!
I cannot delete the relation of systemuser with Orders, because I need it for Solution B.
I'm stuck here...
